# Creating a dynamic list of parameter defined functions

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, dynamic

I'm trying to create a list of functions that is dynamic in size and defines function names like so:

```
size = 10
functionList = {}
For[i=0;i<10;i++, Append[functionList,xi[t]]]

desired output: functionList = {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t],...,x10[t]}
```

Is there such a feature in Mathematica?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ClearAll[functionList]
functionList[n_] := Array[Symbol["x" <> ToString[#]][t] &, n]

functionList[10]
```

> {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t], x6[t], x7[t], x8[t], x9[t], 
>    x10[t]}

Also

```
ClearAll[functionList2]
functionList2[n_] := Through[Array[Symbol["x" <> ToString[#]] &, n] @ t]

functionList2[10]
```

> {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t], x6[t], x7[t], x8[t], x9[t], 
>    x10[t]}

Comment: Perfect, thank you!